# How to set boundfield value to template field control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

[image]

I have gridview output like this .

when I click edit link, I need to pass unitsinstock value should transfer to textbox control. which is present in templatefield.

Here is my c# code:

```
TextBox tt = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox2").ToString();

TextBox text_ref = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");

TextBox3.Text = text_ref.Text;
```

Is there anything wrong? when I debugging `e.NewEdtIndex=0`, `TextBox3=null`.  How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `EditItemTemplate` for this. For exemple, this code above will bound the **unitsinstock** value to **unitsinstock copy** text box when you edit the row.

Change The SqlDataSource as well:

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="unitsinstock" Type="Int32" /> /*Put the correcly type here*/
    /*other fields*/
</UpdateParameters>
```

And the GridView:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="unitsinstock">
  <ItemTemplate>
<asp:label id="labelUnitsinstock" runat="server" text='<%#Eval("unitsinstockActual")%>'>
    </asp:label>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="unitsinstock copy">
  <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
     Text='<%# Bind("unitsinstock") %>'></asp:TextBox>
  </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Take a look here for more information [Using TemplateFields in the GridView Control](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs)

Comment: You should post more c# code to help! But, doing this using the EditTemplate in the GridView makes more sense, less hardcoding!

Comment: Hi,Fals,above your code work fine.but when I update value in database, the values are not updating. any solution...

Comment: actually, I used Sql Datasource to Update data. by using SqlDatasource I created update command. when I update data without any template field,its work fne, but when using template field its not updating